# npgsql not returning rows when passed parameters in select statement

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I am using the following code that was provided in the [npgsql docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/basic-usage.html). I can retrieve data when my query string is `Select * from public.accounts` but this function will not return data when conditions are in the where clause.

I have seen other answers on SO that say to pass the command parameters in the `AddWithValue` function, but this doesn't return anything for me.

The query `Select * from public.accounts where ext_auth0_user_id = 'github|42357689'` DOES return data when I run it directly in pgAdmin, so I am assuming I have some formatting wrong.

```
        var userId = "github|42357689";
        using (var conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("Select * from public.accounts where ext_auth0_user_id = @userId", conn);

            // Retrieve all rows
            using (cmd)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", userId);
                using (NpgsqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        dataTable.Load(reader);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You're comparing `ext_auth0_user_id` against the string `'@userId'`, not the `@userId` parameter's value.  Remove the quotes.

Comment: It may be the single quotes ('@userId').  The single quote indicate TEXT and database may have integers.  Remove single quotes.

Comment: @madreflection unfortunately I still get no data after removing the single quotes around the param. Updated the OP

Answer (score 1):

NpgsqlParameter paramUserId = cmd.Parameters.Add("userId", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, 20);

paramUserId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
paramUserId.value = userId;

NpgsqlParameter paramAnotherId = cmd.Parameters.Add("anotherId", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer);

paramAnotherId.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
paramAnotherId.value = anotherId;

Comment: this results in `CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'string' to 'NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType'`. Any way to parse the string as a NpgsqlDbType?

Comment: PgSqlParameter paramUserId = cmd.Parameters.Add("userId", PgSqlType.VarChar, 20);

paramUserId.value = userId;

sorry long time past im not using postgresql

Comment: @Shapka Update your answer so the correction isn't hidden among the comments. Also, OP is using Npgsql, not dotConnect.

Comment: This solution worked for a text column. However it doesn't work for `character varying` column, which is what I am after...